# Static Factory: Java Design Issue

Tags: java, design-patterns, static, factory-pattern

I have a Base interface that defines some common functionality. Now this base interface can be implemented by more than 50 classes each having some different additional methods. I want to have a static factory that will return an instance of any one of 50 classes depending on a parameter pass to that static factory method.

```
public interface Base {
     public void a();
     public void b();
}

public class myclass implements Base {
     //   a and b implementation

     public String c() {
     }
     public String d() {
     }
}

public class secondclass implements Base {
     //   a and b implementation

     public String e() {
     }
     public String f() {
     }
}
```

How can I implement a static factory method. I am unsure of return type

```
  public synchronized static {return type} getInstance(String arg0) {
         // do something and return any one class based on arg0
  }
```

EDITS:
A scenario

If the passed parameter is 300
I want to return object of class `myclass`

If parameter is 900
I want to return object of class `secondclass`

And so on.
having so many conditions is not feasible.

NOT TO DO

```
public synchronized static {return type} getInstance(String arg0) {
   // do something and return any one class based on arg0
   if(arg0.equals("300")) {
       return new myclass();

   }

}
```

REASON:
This will not be salable. I am developing a public API and class list may increase to 100 or may be 500.
I hope my question is more clear now.

UPDATE:
Very useful points highlighted here and this is what I thought of

```
public abstract class Base {

      public abstract void a();
      public abstract void b();

      public synchronized staticabstract Base getInstance(String arg0);

}


public class myclass extends Base {

     private myclass() {}    // private constructor not publicly instantiate 
     // a and b implementation

     public void c();
     public void d();

     @Override
     public synchronized static abstract Base getInstance(String arg0) {
           if(arg0.equalsIgnoreCase("300")) {      // only 1 if condition
                return new myclass();
           }
     }
}



public class secondclass extends Base {

     private secondclass() {}    // private constructor not publicly instantiate 
     // a and b implementation

     public void e();
     public void f();

     @Override
     public synchronized static abstract Base getInstance(String arg0) {
           if(arg0.equalsIgnoreCase("900")) {      // only 1 if condition
                return new secondclass();
           }
     }
}



Client side:
one applicaiton
Base b=Base.getInstance(300);
if(b instanceof myclass) {

}

second application

Base b=Base.getInstance(900);
if(b instanceof secondclass) {

}
```

Comment: You should really follow the normal java convention and use upper-case letters for your class names.

Comment: @Steinar: Exactly, specially when he/she is talking about implementing some **design pattern**.

Comment: @BheshGurung It is understood that If I am using some static factory method and that too synchronized I am talking in context of factory pattern and singleton classes.

Comment: @Steinar My bad typing mistake I am strictly using java guide for naming

Comment: An option to the if-else pattern is to use a map from string to implementation. However, that is only applicable if the implementation is stateless. If not, you will need to create a new instance every time, either through reflection or explicit use of "new ...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach would be to generify the static method:

```
static <T extends Base> T create(Class<T> type){
  // create concrete instance of type T and return it
}
```

so now the `create` method is parameterized by the actual concrete type `Class` object. You can use `type` to create the appropriate sub-type, either via reflection or using nested `if` statements.

Using generics has the advantage of giving you strong type safety for free, so you can avoid unchecked casts and go home after work with no worries.

**EDIT**: as an example if you had a no-arg constructor in each sub-class you could implement the above as:

```
return type.newInstance();
```

**EDIT 2**: To sum up the discussion, if the factory can't take the type or the logic to create the object depends in a non trivial way on the value of the argument, the only option is the following:

```
static Base create(String someParameter){
  // create the concrete class and return it
}
```

And the client code will look like:

```
Base b = create("myArgument");
if(b instanceof SomeDerived){
  SomeDerived d = (SomeDerived) b;
  // use d
} else if(b instanceof OtherDerived){
  // you get the idea
}
```

Not ideal but there's no way to generify the `create` method without an instance of `Class<? extends Base>`.

Comment: Since the decision to identify subclass of Base is made in the factory method, based on the string passed, this wouldn't help as the callers wouldn't know the type they are going to get, upfront.

Comment: @Vikdor The assumption was that the String somehow represents the type they're going to get back.

Comment: Exactly. If you have to pass an argument anyway you might as well pass the `Class` and get all the type safety juice you need.

Comment: @Powerlord No the string argument will not represent the type that was returned. To be very precise it is not at all related to type it is a constant and based on this constant I want to instantiate one of 50 classes and return that class object to caller.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta, please see my answer below on the concern raised.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I also thought about that but the parameter in getInstance is not related to object type being returned that decision would be taken by the code running in factory method at runtime

Comment: what is the reason of using this approach vs instantiation with constructors ?

Comment: @user3172529 Then I am afraid you're out of luck and will have to do an unchecked cast.

Comment: @user3172529: I think you are trying to intermix the **static-factory-method** and the **factory-method**.

Comment: @user3172529: Also if you need to invoke the methods that are not defined in the interface without an explicit casting, then the only way to achieve that is using generics.

Comment: @user3172529: If you know which "extra" methods you need to invoke, then you also know which sub-type you need, right? And if so, then you should know at compile-time which sub-type you're going to use? Or ... is the usage also decided at runtime?

Comment: I would guess the latter.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta
EDIT 2
Where to have that create method. I mean interface can't have static method. And client would not be same application different applications.

Comment: Wherever you would have put your factory method.

Comment: And just FYI, you could have a static method in an interface with Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

One of the relevant reasons of using static factory over constructors (quote from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)):

> A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike
>   constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return
>   type

So, essentially it can give you ability to write something like :

```
Base x = Factory.getInstance(TypeX.class); 
x.methodOfBase();
```

where `TypeX` could be completely hidden and have private constructor.

You may want to have a look at `java.util.Collections` API implementation, for instance consider static factory method :

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list)
```

as you see return type is an *interface*, and therefore returned object(some hidden implementation of `List`) could only be used *as a List*.

So if you want to use methods `x1()`, `x2()` which are exclusive to subtype `TypeX` and do not belong to `Base` interface, you will have to cast your object to `TypeX` anyway.
In this case you can instantiate `TypeX` directly via constructor (by keeping it public), as static factory won't give you anything.

You may also want to have a look at other 3 reasons to use `static factory` over `constructors` in the book and verify that non of them are applicable to what you described in your question so far.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to use static factory, then you have to return _the Interface type_ . So, either add all set of methods a, b, c, ...z, to you Base interface and have factory, otherwise just instantiate your custom classes with their constructors, since you are going to cast to their return type to use them anyway.

Comment: The complete point of using static factory method is that the sub classes has a private constructor. I dont want them to be publicly instantiated as these objects are very resource consuming.

Comment: @user3172529 To use static factory properly you need both conditions : 1. Use subtypes thru interface. 2. Make them non-instantiable directly(private constructor). Please see `Effective Java` for more details. You only support condition 2., but you need 1. as well. Just extend your `Base` as I suggested in my previous comment

Comment: See my last UPDATE. I hope that will make sense.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it makes sense. What I meant by extending `Base` is just to have interface Base declare all methods a~z() that you want to be in all possible subclasses. If some class `Secondclass` only wants to implement a,b,e,f it can leave implementations of other methods empty {}, or make `Base` an abstract class and provide default implementation for all methods a-z, so subclasses only need to Override impelemntations of methods they are "interested" in. Hope that helps

Comment: What is the use of this. Right now there are around 50 classes and each one of them having 10-15 methods so around 500-700 methods I have to add in Base. Is this making sense to you.

Comment: If you have `500 different` methods in total, and you `want to have static factory`, then yes, it makes sense, because even without factory you will still have to provide these `500 methods` and implementations in your classes. And in `Base` you only have to declare those 500 methods. But if most of your classes don't share same methods, I don't really see a reason for the static factory. Why do you want it so badly ?

Comment: What I mean is, given your example, having static factory you will have to write something like : `TypeX x = (TypeX) Factory.getInstance(TypeX.class); x.methX();` for each of your `TypeA-TypeZ`,

Comment: Without Factory you would have to write `TypeX x = new TypeX(); x.methX();` for each of your subtypes. Do you see any gain in readability / code clarity between those two ? I personally don't

Comment: It would only be useful if you could do : `Base x = Factory.getInstance(TypeX.class); x.methodXofBase()`; so you could do it in the loop, for each TypeA-TypeZ, for example, without code duplication. But for this you have to follow advice in my answer. please Think about it.

Comment: and also please see update in my answer, I tried to summarize. Hope that helps

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. 
1 abstract class having approx 10-15 common methods which are common to each one of 50 classes. Then 50 base classes in different application extending that base class each having approx 10 different method. That is why I planned it like abstract class implementation

Comment: @user3172529 I understand your question and I dont see the reason of using static factory over constructors in your  case. Can you give me one reason please ? If you still want it no matter what, just use answer from `Giovanni Botta` above, this is probably the best approach.

Comment: I don't want my classes to be instantiated publicly I will instantiate them at application startup and will put the object in servlet context to be used. Also the classes that I have are immutable. The class objects are costly to instantiate and will take up to much resources.

Comment: Just use the approach from answer above `static <T extends Base> T getInstance(Class<T> type)` and decide which instance to return from implementation of that method. As you describe in your scenario, you could also maintain a global map(or array/list) of your immutable instances, initialize it once and retrieve it from there thru your static factory API.

Answer (score 0):

The return type would be the interface.

For example:

```
public synchronized static Base getInstance(String arg0) {
    if(arg0.equals("myClass"))
        return new myClass();
    else if (arg0.equals("secondClass"))
        return new secondClass();
}
```

You would call concrete methods like this:

```
Base instance = getInstance("myClass");
((myClass) instance).c();
```

You can also cast it directly:

```
myClass instance = (myClass) getInstance("myClass");
instance.c();
```

Comment: Then how can I access the methods c d e f at run time

Comment: @user3172529 See my edit. You need to cast it to the concrete type.

Comment: Comparing arg0 with class name is not a proper solution in that case I have to write 50 conditions and in future if class increases than more condiitons

Comment: @user3172529 I thought getInstance was in the interface. It doesn't really matter.